# Show custom module information in 1 Module Menu not in 2 Module menu

Tags: magento2.2

I'm creating a custom module by show information of menu in my first module by not in second module show.

[image]

> 1: How to show information menu in my second module?.

[image]

> 2: I need add a New Column to Orders Grid?.

How add a new Column to Orders Grid, Admin Panel: Sales->Orders
(add in database).

Comment: can you please add the code of both module's `etc\adminhtml\menu.xml` file?

Comment: thank you @AbhishekPanchal the problem wos bad writer the .xml in module/view/adminhtml/layout